# Profile image url of current user

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, user, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a custom object Employee__c which has lookup on User object. I have a requirement to get the associated user's **MediumPhotoUrl** field value to display the image in my lwc component. I am using this query -

```
Employee__c emp = [select Id, Name, User__r.MediumPhotoUrl from Employee__c where Id ='xyzabc'];
```

This is not giving any error, However I am only getting User Id, not the field value I queried.
How can I get MediumPhotoUrl field value?

Comment: I dont think there is a MediumPhotoUrl field. Just SmallPhotoUrl and FullPhotoUrl... Medium is only for banner urls.

Comment: There is MediumPhotoUrl field please check

Comment: Oh, my bad - the documentation wasn't showing the field - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm.

Comment: Anyways - where is the component being used? There are certain restrictions on user field access when you enable communities - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

Comment: Yes, there are some restrictions, you can't access user field through child. I used two separate queries and put them in a list of sObject